# how to iterate jquery wildcard selector withouth using each

Tags: jquery, loops, iterator, each

I have to iterate through all the ids starting with "initial_" with a different iterator.

what i tried at the moment is:

```
counter = 5
$("[id^=initial_]").each(function () {
    while (counter > 0) {
        counter--;
        do some stuff here with the current id and manipulate counter
    }
    go to next id
}
```

any idas on how to do it?
thank you for the help

Comment: Why can't you use `.each()`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.. can you maybe rephrase or show some HTML markup with what you want to achieve?

Comment: i was about to add more informations but @davide andreazzini got the point right away! thanks for the interest tho

Comment: @Gotrekk Still, could you tell me why you don't want to use `.each()`?

Comment: sure... because i change the counter with an external ajax call and i need the loop to continue and it doesn't with `each()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is better to use a FOR instead of an EACH and a WHILE
try this:

```
var arr = $("[id^=initial_]");
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){     
    $('#'+arr[i].id).html("I'm the number "+ (i+1))
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! you got the point and it works just like i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$("#yourid").each(function () {
   var counter = 5
        while (counter > 0) {
            counter--;
            do some stuff here with the current id and manipulate counter
        }
        go to next id
    }
```